# The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken_L0RDTUxpdmU1" is not present.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, rotativa

i am trying to produce a PDF using Rotativa MVC

when running it on IE i get

The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken_L0RDTUxpdmU1" is not present.

all other browsers work

this is the link http://dcm.gp.dev.betterbrandagency.com/cash-management-for-your-clients/about-cash-management-for-your-clients/request-illustration/

put 100000 in "No Notice"

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult llustration(DCMIllustration oDCMi)
    {

        return new ViewAsPdf("Downloadllustration", oDCMi) { FileName = "DCM_Illustration.pdf" };
    }
```

Downloadllustration is just a display view

i am puzzled

Comment: Have you included the anti forgery token in the posted form?

Comment: yap, i don't have the errors on Chrome, Firefox or Safari, only on IE

Comment: Do you see the verification token in your cookies? Maybe you can't add the cookie in response due to an IE bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added

Response.AppendHeader("p3p", "*CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");

and worked